# unix: How can I save and display my results in columns and not as a huge string?

Tags: loops, unix, awk, sh

I have this code down below and I want it to display my ending results in columns. But instead it saves them in a large string. Does anyone have any ideas?

```
echo -n Insert the filename
read input

Region=$(awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i=="EVENT")print $(i+2),$(i+3),$(i+4)}' $input)
part1=$(awk '/EVENT/{nr[NR+2]}; NR in nr' $input | awk '{print $1,$2,$5,$6,$7}' $part1 | sed 's/\// /g' $part1 | sed 's/f/    /g' $part1)
part2=$(awk '/EVENT/{nr[NR+6]}; NR in nr' $input | awk '{print $2}' $part2)
echo "$part1 $part2 $Region"
```

The Pattern EVENT is shown multiple times in the file, based on which I created the 3 'variables'.

My results should be like this:

```
String1 String2 Region
String1 String2 Region
String1 String2 Region 
...
```

But instead is displayed as:

```
Part1 Part1 Part1 Part1 ... Part2 Part2 Part2 ... Region Region Region ...
```

UPDATED:
I added "..." in my last echo and now I get my results in one huge column. 
like this:

```
Part1
Part1
Part1
...
Part2
Part2
...
Region
Region
Region
...
```

Comment: Could you please change your `echo` statement to `echo "$part1 $part2 $Region"` once and let us know how it goes then?

Comment: I added the " " and now it gives me one big column. Do you happen to know a way to make them appear one next to each other? 
Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Kindly post sample of input and expected output in your post in CODE TAGS so that we will better understand this question.

Comment: Why are you trying to use `$part1` inside the assignment to `part1` and `$part2` inside the assignment to `part2` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can store the results from your commands in *array* variables and use a `for` loop to output from the three variables in parallel, e.g.:

```
$ a1=( $( echo a b c d ) )
$ a2=( $( echo A B C D ) )
$ a3=( $( echo A3 B3 C3 D3 ) )
$ for ((i=0; i < ${#a1[@]}; i++ )); do
>     echo ${a1[i]}, ${a2[i]}, ${a3[i]}.
> done
a, A, A3.
b, B, B3.
c, C, C3.
d, D, D3.
$
```

Compare with the version that does not uses array variables (note that there is one level of parentheses missing)

```
$ a1=$( echo a b c d ) ; a2=$( echo A B C D ) ; a3=$( echo A3 B3 C3 D3 )
$ echo $a1 $a2 $a3
a b c d A B C D A3 B3 C3 D3
$
```

Answer (score 0):

combining columns in `bash` is with `paste`

e.g.

```
$ paste <(echo -e "a\nb\nc") <(echo -e "1\n2\n3")

a       1
b       2
c       3
```

Most likely you can do everything in one `awk` script but not clear what you're trying to achieve in the scripts posted; your variable names appear on the right hand side as filenames as well.